# A question about using KeyTab files to authenticate an Active Directory user to a Linux WEB Server (or any other App running on Linux)

Tags: kerberos, keytab

Can someone please help me with the following

Assume I have an AD Domain and a 'standalone Linux host' which is not joined to the AD domain and there is no trust relationship in place between the AD and Linux of any kind.

Next I have a Kerberos aware application running on the Linux Server (WEB Server for example or other app) which is .

In order to an AD user to authenticate to the Linux hosted WEB/App using a KeyTab file 
(created in Windows and setup on Linux).  Does the Linux host need to be AD-Joined, in order to keyTab (single sign one) authentication to work?

Meaning if the Linux server was never joined to any domain of any kind (standalone), Would I still be able to user a KeyTab file to authenticate a user coming in from an AD Domain?

Thanks all
Charlie

Comment: There is no relationship between a keytab (= a file containing an encrypted password, for automatic Kerberos auth) and Single Sign-On (= a way to use existing Kerberos creds on the local machine to authenticate on a remote service). Typically the kerberised service uses a keytab to authenticate with its SPN (Service Principal Name), yes, but that's just a minuscule part of the setup.

Comment: Many Hadoop or Kafka clusters running in corporate data centers use Kerberos authentication, using AD as their back-end KDC, without "joining" the Linux hosts to AD. They just need the appropriate SPN to be defined e.g. `HTTP/server.name.with.domain@REA.LM` for the UIs and REST APIs (service code `HTTP`) and, with AD, that requires a "technical" account to which the SPN is mapped -- because AD does not support the same syntax as Kerberos for user names...

Comment: Caveat: Kerberos is dark magic. Find an expert on both sides -- i.e. both an AD admin and someone who knows well the specific web server that you want to use. And be prepared for some very-low-level debugging to find out what works and what does not _(e.g. does the firewall accept UDP on port 88? does my server have a canonical DNS name, and a valid clock? why does Java have a default timeout of 30s before failover while C/Python have 30ms? how can I use a load balancer in front of servers that use distinct SPNs? how do I change the SPN password without downtime? ...)_

Comment: Thanks very much all, I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out with my queston, there is some very helpful information in those answers.